# Have updates significantly improved the quality of Aliens Colonial Marines?

Tags: aliens-colonial-marines

The initial release of Aliens Colonial Marines was a crushing disappointment for me. The game is just shy of one year old now. I'm curious as to how playable the game's campaign and online modes have become.

Reviewing Gearbox software support's [update page](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1065/aliens-colonial-marines-update) it looks like they've put a good bit of patchwork into it. Have any of these changes resulted in a serious improvement to the game's quality?

Comment: Define improvement.  What you're asking is rather opinion based, as the game was playable when it was released, and not much else.

Comment: Improvements as in noticeable improvements in AI behavior, refined graphics (shading, motion blur, texture resolution), etc. And yes, this is kind of asking for opinions on the distinction between the initial release and the latest update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to purchase a PS3 copy of Aliens Colonial Marines for $8.00 on Amazon - still in the shrink wrap. The updates only provide marginal improvements. A more specific list of changes in Gearbox Software's PS3 updates can be found [here](https://gearboxsoftware.zendesk.com/entries/23137591-PlayStation-3-Update-Information).